# Exact differences in "hibernate TABLE vs Sequence generation strategies"?

Tags: hibernate

**I read in docs that SEQUENCE generation strategy uses common db sequence for all entities**(all tables) **whereas TABLE generation strategy uses different db sequence for each entity**(table),but doc says TABLE generation strategy is little expensive.Is it fine to use TABLE generation strategy for a table that does carryies >=1000 records ?.

Comment: it would be nice sir if you put comment telling wt is wrong with this question.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with spring MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you read is incorrect.

The sequence generation strategy uses a database sequence, and you can specify which sequence to use.

The table strategy, as its name indicates, uses a database table containing counters to generate IDs. It kinds of simulate a real database sequence by storing the last generated ID for each entity in a database table. The advantage of this strategy is that it works on every database, even those that don't have sequences. But if you use a database that supports sequences, the sequence strategy is both easier, more intuitive, and faster.

Note that the number of elements in a table doesn't change anything to how fast or slow it is to generate IDs for this table.

I suggest you read the Hibernate reference documentation.